# ubuntu 18.04 question about a script that used to work now it doesnt

Tags: bash, scripts

This script named vpnon.sh used to work from the desktop.

```
#!/bin/bash

xterm -e "windscribe connect; sleep 2.0"
```

This used to work from the desktop but it stopped working after fresh install.
Can somebody help?

If I run from terminal it works fine. I started from scratch, made a new one, same results.

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Comment: Use absolute paths for `xterm` and `windscribe`.

Comment: @waltinator if I try to run it from the desktop  by double clicking it only opens to be edited it will not run. If the path was an issue it would not run from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:Its been a very long time and I forgot the trick. Open files, go to the top of the screen and click on files, click on preferences, click behavior tab, under executable text files check run them. I am using ubuntu 18.04.3 maybe a little different in different versions.